# Django - Ошибка 404, как пофиксить url?

Tags: python, html, django, url, http-status-code-404

****Доброго времени суток**, при разработке моего первого сайта на Django столкнулся с проблемой.** При открытии Url (переход с главной страницы на другую) - появляется ошибка Page Not Found (404). Читал документацию к Django, вроде все делал исходя из написанного там.

*html код: (фрагмент меню для перехода по сайту)*

```
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">О НАС</a>
    </li>
```

*views.py код:*

```
def index(request):
return render(request, 'waterprojects/index.html')

def aboutus(request):
return render(request, 'waterprojects/aboutus.html')
```

*urls.py код:*

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index),
path('aboutus/', views.aboutus)
]
```

**Из-за чего может возникать ошибка 404 Page Not Found в данной ситуации?**

Comment: В разных местах то `aboutus.html`, то `abouts.html` (без u).

Comment: это я допустил ошибку в написании вопроса, извиняюсь за невнимательность при публикации, сейчас поправлю. ошибка всё та же, я уже и полное расположение файла вписывал, всё равно не работает. с чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала вам надо отредактировать все места кода и исправить ошибки с наименованием about, а затем скорректировать
urls.py
Пример

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index),
path('aboutus/', views.aboutus, name='about')
]
```

Затем скорректировать html шаблон

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about'  %}">О НАС</a>
</li>
```

Таким способом вы передадите основную работу url dispatcher

Линк для чтения
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#examples

P.S. Для страниц типа about us лучше использовать django flatpages
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/flatpages/

**Небольшой UPD** почему лучше использовать url dispatcher:
На первый взгляд кажется, что проще написать url в шаблоне следующим видом

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="aboutus/about.html">О НАС</a>
</li>
```

Тогда urls.py будет выглядеть вот так

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index),
path('aboutus/', views.aboutus)
]
```

Казалось бы, а в чём проблема так сделать ? Ну допустим к нам приходит лид и говорит, что нужно переделать ссылку на

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index),
path('about/', views.aboutus)
]
```

Мне как разработчику придётся в шаблоне поменять линк

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="about/about.html">О НАС</a>
</li>
```

А теперь представим, что у нас допустим 100 ссылок в проекте, и ещё они пересекаются, тогда менять руками файлики, ну мягко говоря не круто, хотя если вы хотите списать часы )

Вот, поэтому нам проще задавать name в urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index),
path('aboutus/', views.aboutus, name='about')
]
```

и шаблон

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about'  %}">О НАС</a>
</li>
```

И тогда не зависимо от смены ссылки мы будем обращаться по имени к этой ссылки.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ValeriyLeonov у вас заработало ?

Comment: да, заработало!